# How to disable the Follow button across Farm using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, social

Is there a easy way to disable the Follow Button across the Farm using Powershell.(This request is for SharePoint 2013)

I am trying to do the same through DocAve - Policy Enforcer but it doesn't seem to be working.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This script goes through the hierarchy and disables the Following Content feature in every WebSite. You get an error message for every site where the feature is not active or missing. This can be ignored

```
$w = Get-SPWeb http://MySharePointURL | ForEach{ $_.URL }
Get-SPFeature -Web $w |%{ Disable-SPFeature -Identity "FollowingContent" -URL $w -Confirm:$false}
```

Source: [Deactivate social feature MySite, Newsfeed, OneDrive, Sync, Share & Follow in SharePoint 2013](http://www.sharepointtalk.net/2014/10/deactivate-social-feature-mysite.html)

Comment: can the http://MySharePointURl be a WebApp URL because when I put the WebApp url it only does for th Root WeSite and not for subsites under it ForEx - my webapp is http://sp13.bla.com and I have other site collection starting with http://sp13.bla.com/sites/fin and http://sp13.bla.com /teams/hr how do I make it happen under the subsites deep down under the sitecollection .I have around 90 SiteCollections and thousand of SubSites under it.

Comment: @SavantProdigy Not really. You need to use the mysite host URL, since the follow feature lives in all mysite instances...

Comment: now my mysites looks like this http://mysite.bla.com:8080/ I tried that in the above powerhsell no change?

Comment: Just an FYI I am trying to disable the Follow button on the extreme right top corner side of the SharPoint Page sorry if I was not clear on my explanation

Comment: @SavantProdigy Have you read the link? (No worries) :)